# How do you reference a Wikimedia image if the file name is non-Latin?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki, unicode, wikimedia-commons

I am trying to reference the wikipedia commons image in an english wikipedia info box. The image is a wikimedia commons picture with a Japanese name. Somehow it does not allow it to be placed there. Is there a special way to reference non romantic language file names in images?

Comment: Could you show us what exactly did you try and how did that fail?

Comment: Nassign, you may want to check the meaning of `romantic` on english.stackexchange.com ...

Comment: I replaced "romantic" with "latin".

Answer (score 2):

You can reference pictures with non-latin names in infoboxes and anywhere, no problem.

Just use copy-paste like you would do for a latin characters URL.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask this on en-wp, not here! see **[WP:PICTURE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aPicture_tutorial)**, you can use the methods described on that page for any kind of file name, just copy the complete file name and paste it in the wiki code.

If you have more questions like this, see these pages on English Wikipedia:

- [Wikipedia:Village pump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aVillage_pump)
- [Wikipedia:IRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aIRC)

Comment: I think this question is okay here. Though asking directly on Wikipedia is certainly a valid option too (and probably a better one).